# Setting the icon_theme_path in python script

Tags: unity, python, scripts, icons, indicator

I've made a python script to add a new indicator in the systray on Ubuntu Unity. When i set a specific folder for the icon, the icon appears in the systray.

Exemple :

```
self.ind.set_icon_theme_path("/home/myuser/directory/")
self.ind.set_icon("the_icon")
```

But, how i can change the icon_theme_path line to use the current folder where is the script.py ?

Like this :

```
self.ind.set_icon_theme_path("/home/$user/directory/")
self.ind.set_icon("the_icon")
```

Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for the home folder, it might be worth getting the `HOME` variable as such:

```python
import os
self.ind.set_icon_theme_path(os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], 'directory'))
self.ind.set_icon("the_icon")
```

otherwise, for if you need the script's folder location you can use the following:

```python
import os
self.ind.set_icon_theme_path(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
self.ind.set_icon("the_icon")
```

Reference: [Find current directory and file's directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5137497/2734389)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import os
current_directory = os.getcwd()
self.ind.set_icon_theme_path(current_directory)
```

More about: [Find current directory and file's directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory)

Comment: os.getcwd() dont work for me, but i found this code :

        `import os
        self.ind.set_icon_theme_path(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
        self.ind.set_icon("my_icon")`

Thanks Radu Rădeanu ;)

Comment: @minerz029 Would be appreciated that when you downvote an answer/question to leave a comment.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu You shouldn't assume that the working directory is the script folder. The OP asked for file location which might be changed by using `cd` to a different folder and have unexpected results.